# Can you capture arrays in a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm in a situation in a multithreaded environment where I have a thread that receives data from a socket, and I want to send that data into a messaging queue.

For instance, something like this:

```
char buf[N];
size_t len = ::recv(buf, ...);
queue.send([buf,len] {
    //stuff
});
```

But that won't work since `buf` could go out of scope, or get overwritten by the next `::recv()`. Now I *COULD* copy it into a `string`/`std::vector`/whatever and pass *THAT* thing by value:

```
char buf[N];
size_t len = ::recv(buf, ...);
std::string my_data(buf, len);
queue.send([my_data](){ /* stuff */ });
```

But there I'm incurring an extra copy, right? Is there a way to get that same functionality without the extra overhead?

Comment: Why don't you use `std::array`? You don't have to pass by value, you can pass by reference, i.e. `[&]`.

Comment: `buf` could go out of scope, but the copy in the lambda won't.  You may still have an extra copy, however, depending on whether `queue.send` is optimized for accept rvalue references.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can.  The Standard says that (5.1.2p21):

> When the lambda-expression is evaluated, the entities that are captured by copy are used to direct-initialize each corresponding non-static data member of the resulting closure object.  (For array members, the array elements are direct-initialized in increasing subscript order.)

which makes it clear that a lambda can capture an array by copy.

Comment: Oh cool, the whole array buf gets copied, not just the pointer? That's pretty nifty!

Comment: @Barry: As long as the variable being captured actually is an array, not just a pointer to one, yes.

Comment: Wow this is so unexpected! Just realized this now - capturing in a lambda a variable defined like this: `char buf[N]` has completely different outcomes then capturing a variable defined by `char * buf`. I thought that for all matters these two are considered the same thing by the compiler...

Comment: @FMA: Not even close to "all matters".  They are different for `sizeof`, for binding references, for copying when placed inside a class.  There's really only one place they are treated the same -- in a function signature.  In every single other way they are different types, with a one-way implicit conversion.