# Create an array inside a lambda capture

Tags: c++, c++17

Lambda captures allow us to create new variables, e.g:

```
auto l = [x = 10]() { };
```

I know this also works for `std::array` but what about C style arrays?

To be clear, I don't want to copy or reference an array here. I want to create a new one inside the capture clause.

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? Why do you want a C style array rather than `std::array`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes I have but I couldn't figure out a syntax for it. And this question is about C style arrays because I'm curious.

Comment: why not inside the lambda body? `[x = 10]{ int A[3]={1,2,3}; return A[2]; };`

Comment: @OrenIshShalom because that's a different scope. The lifetime would be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't work as currently specified for C style arrays. For one, the capture syntax doesn't allow for declarators to compound types. I.e. the following are invalid as a capture

```
*x = whatever
x[] = whatever
(*x)() = whatever
```

So we can't "help dictate" how the captured variable's type is supposed to be determined. The capture specification always makes it equivalent to essentially one of the following initialization syntaxes

```
auto x = whatever
auto x { whatever }
auto x ( whatever )
```

Now, this initializes `x` from `whatever`. This will always involve, in some shape or form, expressions. Since expressions never keep their C array type outside of certain contexts (`sizeof`, `decltype`, etc..) due to their decay into pointers, `x`'s type can never be deduced as an array type.

Comment: And even if there was no decay, arrays aren't copy-initialisable in the first place.

Comment: @eerorika but you can capture them by value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423695/can-you-capture-arrays-in-a-lambda.

Comment: @eerorika - Well, they don't have to be, strictly speaking. There's the edge case of using a brace enclosed initializer list for the capture's initialzier. This allows a capture to become a `std::initializer_list`. if we had `auto foo[] = {1, 2, 3};` well defined, as well as the the declarator syntax in lambdas, then potentially arrays could be used as lambda members.